# Android fragment keep view after popbackstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I create android app. In my app I use 2 fragment.
Fragment A -> Fragment contain Google Map View.
Fragment B -> Fragment Detail. (Display when click on marker of google map).

Here is follow:

Open A -> Click marker on google map -> Open B. (Notes. B added to backstack).

Now I popBackStack B to resume fragment A. But View of Fragment B not removed after fragment B popBackStack.

I also check, I can touch and control map view normally.

Please help me understand why View of Fragment B not removed.

**Update**

Problem only happened when in Fragment B I open fragment dialog then popBackStack fragment from this dialog. 
Detail: 
In fragment B, I open one Dialog Fragment .
In this dialog I have button close. If user Click to this button then fragment B will be popBackStack.

Comment: Are you using `.add()`or `replace()` method while calling your fragment??

Comment: Have you added your Fragment A into the backstack? Do post your code also.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I used method replace(). Please take a look my edit.

Comment: Have you called popBackStack while dismissed your dialog? After dismiss dialog you need to call popBackStack .

Comment: Yes, I called popBackStack. (If I not call Popbackstack => fragment B still keep). But my case is Fragment B popBackStack then user can touch & control Fragment B. Problem is View of Fragment B not remove :|

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .remove(fragB)
    .show(fragA)
    .commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```